# Make home button on toolbar change color when selected

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-homebutton

I'm a bit of an Android newbie. I have a toolbar on my MainActivity which has a home button on the left (backarrow). I'm setting it like this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I noticed that on other Android apps when I hit the home button it will change background color momentarily to show the user that the click has been registered, and this is what I want to achieve. How can I do this? Is it a simple config change or is it something I have to implement myself?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can go with android v7 toolbar. A fully customized toolbar..

Comment: @pakflowova You want an the Toolbar to change into a different color when the back button is pressed only for a few seconds, right? If so, you'll have to implement it yourself, and I don't think it's gonna be simple.